# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'commands')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've almost fixed my bot and now its giving this error :-

```
/Users/roopa/Desktop/projects/LLbot/src/handlers/commandHandler.js:27
    client.application.commands.set(commandsArray);
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'commands')
    at loadCommands (/Users/roopa/Desktop/projects/LLbot/src/handlers/commandHandler.js:27:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/roopa/Desktop/projects/LLbot/src/bot.js:274:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v20.2.0
```

My commandHandler.js code :-

```
function loadCommands(client) {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const ascii = require('ascii-table');
    const table = new ascii().setHeading('Commands', 'Status');

    let commandsArray = [];

    const commandsFolder = fs.readdirSync('/Users/roopa/Desktop/projects/LLbot/src/Commands');
    
    for (const folder of commandsFolder) {
        const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`/Users/roopa/Desktop/projects/LLbot/src/Commands/${folder}`).filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for (const file of commandFiles) {
            const commandFile = require(`/Users/roopa/Desktop/projects/LLbot/src/Commands/${folder}/${file}`);

            client.commands.set(commandFile.data.name, commandFile);
            commandsArray.push(commandFile.data.toJSON());
            table.addRow(file, '');
            continue;
        }
    }

    client.application.commands.set(commandsArray);

    return console.log(table.toString(), '\nCommands Loaded')
}
module.exports = { loadCommands };
```

Is it giving me errors because my 'commandsArray' is empty? idk for sure tho.

aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb *(ignore this , i didnt have much to explain so did this.)*

Comment: The error says _"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'commands')"_. This is about `client.application`, whose property `commands` is read in order to call its `set()` method. Apparently `client.application` is `null` and, because of that, it does not have the property `commands`.

Comment: This is a common JavaScript error. There is nothing specific to Node.js or discord.js here. Read about [`TypeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) in the JavaScript documentation. The first example in the documentation is similar to what happens in your code. This is a coding error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set the property `commands` of an undefined property `applications`.

Adding `applications.commands` under the form of an object should fix it:

```
client.application = { commands: commandsArray };
```